# A characterisation of Hamiltonian vector fields.

Tags: differential-forms, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and let $X\colon M\rightarrow TM$ be a vector field on $M$.

> **Theorem.** The vector field $X$ is Hamiltonian if and only if the following two conditions are fulfilled:
>
> - If $(\phi_t)_t$ is the flow of $X$, one has ${\phi_t}^*\omega=\omega$,
> - For all loop $c\colon]-1,1[\rightarrow M$, one has $\displaystyle\int_ci_X\omega=0$.

**Proof.** Let us proceed by double implication.

- Assume $X$ is Hamiltonian, then there exists a smooth map $H\colon M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that:
  $$i_X\omega=\mathrm{d}H.$$
  Therefore, the differential form $i_x\omega$ of degree $1$ is exact and its integral vanish on all loops drawn on $M$. Furthermore, using Cartan's formula for the Lie derivative and since $\omega$ is closed, one gets:
  $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}({\phi_t}^*\omega)_{\vert t=0}=0.$$
  **I do not know how to deduce that ${\phi_t}^*\omega=\omega$.** If I use directly the definition of the pullback, I get:
  $$({\phi_t}^*\omega)_x(v,w)=\omega_{\phi_t(x)}(\mathrm{d}_x\phi_t\cdot v,\mathrm{d}_x\phi_t\cdot w),$$
  which does not look to promising.
- **I will assume that $M$ is connected (is it necessary?).** Assume that $X$ fulfils the two given conditions, let $m\in M$, for all $x\in M$, I would like to define:
  $$H(x):=\int_{c_x}i_X\omega,$$
  where $c_x$ is any path from $m$ to $x$. According to the second condition, the result will not depend on $c_x$. Therefore, the only difficulty is to choose it so that $H$ is smooth and I don't know how to proceed.

Whence the result. $\Box$

Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}({\phi_t}^*\omega)_{\vert t=t_0}=\phi_{t_0}^*(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}({\phi_t}^*\omega)_{\vert t=0}).$$
 implies that $\phi_t^*(\omega)$ is constant and is equal to $\phi_{0}^*(\omega)=\omega$ since $\phi_0^*$ is the identity.